# Docker: some ghost images are messing up with the memory

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-machine, docker-registry

The docker my team and I are using is frequently running out of space. Usually we fixed this by deleting the dangling images. But now at the moment there are 5 running containers with 7 images and the memory is full. Even the log file can't write its output. So as I described there are like 15 images (docker images --all), but when I type `docker info` it says that there are 132 images.

```
root@dockersrv:/var/lib/docker# docker info
Containers: 10
Images: 132
Storage Driver: aufs
Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
Backing Filesystem: extfs
Dirs: 154
Dirperm1 Supported: true
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.16.0-30-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 2
Total Memory: 15.67 GiB
Name: dockersrv
ID: ``
WARNING: No swap limit support
```

As far as I remeber, somebody manged to delete the registry container, and we created a new one. My thoughts are that all of these images are associated with the old registry. So any idea how to delete them and free up some space. Any other advices about how to increase its memory and what to perform apart deleting dangling images and old containers would be much appreciated.

Comment: `docker images -a` will show all your images. But this will also contain child images of your existing images. With `docker rmi $(docker images | grep "^<none>" | awk "{print $3}")` you can delete all unused images with tag <none>:<none> but I would think you already did that.

Comment: When you explore a bit with `du -sh`. Which folder inside `/var/lib/docker/` contains the a lot of gigabytes? Most of the time dangling volumes are causing issues.

Comment: the whole dir is 60 gigs, 15 of them are for the aufs and 40 for the volumes folder

Comment: The strange thing is that docker images --all returns around 40 results(together with the intermediate ones). But the status says that there are 150 of them ...

Comment: Maybe some volume of your old registry that is still somewhere. What's the output of `du -sh /var/lib/docker/volumes` ?

Comment: All of the subfolders are kylobytes apart from two. The first one is 11gigs and the second one 23gigs

Comment: Those big volumes are used by your containers?

Comment: Just one of them. The other one seems to be the one for the old registry. I guess that I can delete it?

Comment: Yes you can delete that. Clean way is using this command https://coderwall.com/p/hdsfpq/docker-remove-all-dangling-volumes

Comment: The problem is that we are using version 1.8 which does not include the volume prune command ;(

Comment: Just performing sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/the-specific-volume is also possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help mate :) post the last comment as an answer if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker images -a` will show all your images. But this will also contain child images of your existing images.

The first steps to 'clean up' your docker environment is to delete the stopped docker containers which are showed when you perform `docker ps -a`. You can not delete docker images as long as an instance of an image (container) exists. Even when it's not running anymore.

```
docker rm -v `docker ps -a`
```

After deleting the stopped containers you're able to delete unused images with for example:

```
docker images -q |xargs docker rmi
```

As you can see there are multiple ways/commands to delete your containers and images.
The `-v` option (used when deleting containers) will delete the container volume which is also an important part.

The docker volumes are stored in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` and this contains the content of your containers. In the question was some issue about an old registry which was deleted. Than it's very important to check if the volume of the registry is also deleted.

In the newer versions of docker you can delete dangling volumes with:

```
docker volume rm `docker volume ls -q -f dangling=true`
```

You can also just delete the right folder + restart docker.

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/docker/volumes/the-specific-volume
```